# Simplify TypeScript expression

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm pretty new to Typescript and came across something that seems a bit redundant to me and I'd like to simplify, if possible.

My goal is to have a ButtonGroups component which allows one or multiple Buttons as children and no other type of React component.

```js
interface ButtonGroupProps {
    alignment?: "horizontal" | "vertical";
    children: Array<ReactElement<ButtonProps>> | ReactElement<ButtonProps>;
}
```

Is there a way to simplify this expression for the children type, or would you suggest another approach to reach my goal?

Kind Regards

Comment: That looks fine to me. It's only two options.

Comment: Can you explain what here is redundant?  You could write `type OrArray<T> = T | Array<T>` and then `children: OrArray<ReactElement<ButtonProps>>`, but I don't see that as a win unless you are going to use `OrArray` a bunch of times.

Comment: The fact I had to write `ReactElement<ButtonProps>` twice seemed redundant to me. But it seems this is the way to go - Thank you two.

Comment: You could extract the `ReactElement<ButtonProps>` into its own type but that really seems unnecessary unless you will use that type in other places as well

Comment: I will consider extracting this part If I need it somewhere else - Thanks!

Comment: Note that if your goal is to have `<ButtonGroup><div/></ButtonGroup>` or similar fail because `<div/>` isn't a button, sadly the above won't do that. There have been several questions posted previously about how to use TypeScript to require children be of a specific type of element, and the answer is: it can't do that.

Comment: The only simplification I see here is `children: Array<ReactElement<ButtonProps>> | ReactElement<ButtonProps>;` -> `children: ReactElement<ButtonProps>[] | ReactElement<ButtonProps>;`